# predicting manufacturing survival time

Tags: survival, hazard

My task is to improve widget quality from a high volume manufacturing process.  The survival data is 99% right censored, since most products do not fail, and rapid analysis long before failure is necessary to get the business value.

The goals are to:

1. change the manufacturing process to stop making high risk widgets.  This needs "effect size" in the language of Survival Analysis
2. select widgets at high risk of return for separate handling.  This needs widget level predictions.

The right censoring makes Survival Analysis appropriate (which I haven't done before) relative to ordinary prediction (which I've done lots of).  I have thousands of covariates about the widgets, making closed form methods desirable.  Accelerated Failure Time models seem popular in manufacturing.   The log-logistic distribution is a commonly used Accelerated Failure Time (AFT) model with a closed form.

My questions are:

1. Can I get effect sizes from AFT?
2. Can I get observation level predictions from AFT?
3. Can I scale AFT to tens of thousands of covariates?
4. Can you propose a Python implementation of an AFT?
5. Can you propose an R implementation of an AFT?
6. Do you have an alternate to AFT to propose?

thanks